# Is time dilation different in optically dense materials?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, time-dilation

Recently in class we started doing some basic special relativity, and our teacher showed us the light clock and how you can calculate the Lorentz factor and time dilation based on that.

However, I was wondering what would happen if we did the experiment in something optically dense such as glass, where light travels slower.

Would time dilation still be the same as in a vacuum, or would time approach zero as you approached the speed of light in glass?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but light technically doesn't travel slower inside a medium. It's just because of the fact that the medium is dense, light get balanced around by matter and so it takes more time for it to reach the destination, so macroscopically it appears slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we call 'light speed' is really the speed of information. Light happens to go that fast simply because its massless. But when light is in glass, its associated/bound by with the massive particles producing that permittivity and permeability. That is, the EM also depends on the EM of those massive particles. The speed of information remains the same. Consider that the effect applies only to part of the spectrum.

Comment: @GiulioCrisanti To answer what would happen in glass: time dilation applies the same way, while the lower speed of light, as observed at macroscopic scale, is subject to the relativistic addition of velocities. Which makes the whole thing a lot harder to explain from first principles.